# React Error: Element Type is Invalid with named exports

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting uptown speed with react hooks and functions and I have three files. One provides a context `SummaryContext`, the second is a class component which consumes the context `WikiSummary` and the third displays it `Title`.

However, I get the below error, and for all my messing around (still learning) I can't figure out why I get this error.

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `WikiSummary`.
```

### Summary Context

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react'
export const SummaryContext = createContext(null);
```

### Wiki Summary

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Title} from "./components/Title"
import {SummaryContext} from "../../contexts/SummaryContext"

import "../../App.css"

class WikiSummary extends Component {

render() {
  return (
    <>
      <SummaryContext.Provider value = "hello from context">
      <Title />
      </SummaryContext.Provider>
    </>

  );
}
}
export default WikiSummary;
```

### Title

```
import React, {useContext} from "react"
import {SummaryContext} from "../../../contexts/SummaryContext"

export function Title(){
  const message = useContext(SummaryContext)

  return(
    <div>
      <h2>{message}</h2>
    </div>
  )

}
```

A sandbox displays a different error as seen in the sanbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-example-forked-rly0d?file=/src/components/Title.js

Comment: Where is `Summary` definition?

Comment: In the first file `SummaryContext`. Ah I see. Two seconds.

Comment: Can you check are you importing correct path for `Summary ` context? Codewise looks fine. I am assuming you have valid `Summary` component

Comment: try commenting <Summary/> just to verify the problem not in Summary component

Comment: Yep, that got rid of that error. But now I'm getting `TypeError: render is not a function. (In 'render(newValue)', 'render' is an instance of Object)`

Comment: I guess your summary component's import will be `import { Summary } from "./components/Summary"` (if named export)

Comment: I've completely removed the `summary` component to deal with this exclusively with `Title`. And removing the curly braces in the import of `WikiSummary` gives me: `Attempted import error: './components/Title' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Title').`

Comment: can u share the code for Summary component

Comment: @TheMightyLlama, Could you please create a codesandbox may be forking this https://codesandbox.io/s/8yl47pn1kj and reproduce your issue there for better understanding..

Comment: @prabeen90, I've removed the summary component and updated the question.

Comment: @ManirajMurugan, I'll attempt to put it on sandbox

Comment: Sandbox added: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-example-forked-rly0d?file=/src/components/Title.js

Comment: @TheMightyLlama, Is this is what you want? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-example-forked-8w5b7

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it. I don't know why this works over the solution proposed in this video which also works. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhMKvyLRWo0 Feel free to add the answer and I'll accept ti.

Comment: @TheMightyLlama, Added as a solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SummaryContext.Consumer` uses a render prop, specifically a function as a child component, so it expects its immediate child to be a function.

This is the reason you got the error,

> TypeError: render is not a function. (In 'render(newValue)', 'render'
> is an instance of Object)

In your case, you can just move the div inside the function like,

```
import React from "react";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { SummaryContext } from "./SummaryContext";

export function Title() {
  const message = useContext(SummaryContext);

  return (
    <SummaryContext.Consumer>
      {(value) => (
        <div>
          <h2>{message}</h2>
        </div>
      )}
    </SummaryContext.Consumer>
  );
}
```

Also here `value` itself gives the message you wish to display so you could either use `<h2>{value}</h2>` straight a way or else you could also take your previous way of assigning it to a variable `message` and the call inside the template.

[image: Edit React: Context Example (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-example-forked-yrd7g?file=/src/components/Title.js

I updated the `react` and `react-dom` version to 16.13.0
and removed `SummaryContext.Consumer`

if you need consumer api or cant upgrade  react version then you should pass a function as children to `SummaryContext.Consumer`

```js
import React from "react";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { SummaryContext } from "./SummaryContext";

export function Title() {
  return (
    <SummaryContext.Consumer>
      {(value) => (
        <div>
          <h2>{value}</h2>
        </div>
      )}
    </SummaryContext.Consumer>
  );
}
```